# Debugging/running GWT app in Intellij 2016.2.1

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm having some trouble "all of a sudden" running my GWT app in my development environment. I have a fun configuration that is non-super-dev-mode and a super-dev mode configuration. I can only run in super-dev-mode now, and I can't put breakpoints on the client side.

It doesn't really have any specific in it. it used to work, and I used to be able to debug. This one launches to Firefox 24.3.0, the last version to support the GWT dev plugin.

[image]
The super dev one sort of works. It runs to Chrome, as it uses the Intellij developer plugin. But, my breakpoints on the client don't trigger. Breakpoints on the server classes do trigger.

[image]

I'm on GWT 2.6.1, and I have this line in my module xml file:

> `<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>`

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading GWT to 2.7.0. SDM works much better in GWT 2.7.  Classic Dev Mode should work fine with 2.6.1 and 2.7.0. By the way it works up to firefox 26. I'd delete your cache and try again.

Comment: My main desire to stick with GWT 2.6 was because I could use the GUI Designer (in eclipse, can't do it in IntelliJ).

Comment: it seems to be able to debug the client side now. not sure why it wasn't working before.